# Identify all nodes at same location

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit, ios9

I have a iOS app that draws a grid of sprites on screen. I then have another sprite representing a colour  which I can drag and drop over the grid. My question is how do I identify which sprite on the grid it was dragged onto?

Ultimately I want to allow a user to drag a colour sprite over another sprite, so I can change the colour, as per the users selection.

The code below only returns the 2nd sprite (the top one) at the location, whereas I need to identify both sprites at that location.

```
 override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)
{
    print("tocuhes ended")

    for touch in touches
    {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let nodeAtLocation = self.nodeAtPoint(location)

        let nodeName = nodeAtLocation.name

        print("Node Name \(nodeName)")


    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with nodesAtPoint : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/nodesAtPoint:  You can give a names to your nodes and then search the array returned by nodesAtPoint method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch in touches
    {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let nodesAtLocation = self.nodesAtPoint(location)

        for node in nodesAtLocation {

            let nodeName = node.name

            print("Node Name \(nodeName)")

        }
    }
}
```